# How to forward Server sent events in NextJS api

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-sent-events

I have a Next.js api like this (`/api/events/index.js`):

```
import EventSource from 'eventsource';
import { getAccessToken, withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default withApiAuthRequired(async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    const { accessToken } = await getAccessToken(req, res);

    res.writeHead(200, {
      Connection: 'keep-alive',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    });
    const eventSource = new EventSource(
      `http://localhost:8000/v1/event-stream`,
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } },
    );

    eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
      res.write(`data: ${e.data}\n\n`);
      //  res.end();
    };
  }
});
```

Essentially, I'm trying to make a request on a backend API SSE endpoint that requires an authorization bearer token (preferably, the access token should be available only on Next.js API side). After an event is received, it should be written in response to of a new event stream.

In React client code, I simply subscribe to these SSE's like this:

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const eventSource = new EventSource(`http://localhost:3000/api/events`);
    eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    };
    return () => {
      eventSource.close();
    };
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Where's the problem? Nothing is received on the client side.
When I try to call `res.end()` on the API side, an event is received on the client side, but the event stream keeps reconnecting... like, every second. Basically, the connection is not kept alive. How can I forward the result of my SSE?

**EDIT:**
While the `no-cache, no-transform` attribute in the `Content-Type` header solves the receiving of events, the issue still remains with unclosed server-side connections. Essentially, on client disconnect, the server-side SSE connection should be closed too.

Comment: Hey! I replicated your problem locally (without nextjs-auth0) and found that it broke when I did not have the following Cache-Control header: "no-cache, no-transform". This is assuming everything else in the setup works as expected. I referenced this github issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9965

Comment: @rexessilfie Hey hey! That indeed helped. Works fine now, except for one small important thing... The event stream on the API side is not closed on client disconnection. Basically, on page refresh, a new connection on `http://localhost:8000/v1/event-stream` is being made. Which is absolutely terrible...

Comment: Hey @Brainslav Lazic, did you figure this out? If I understand your issue correctly, perhaps you could imagine only establishing the event source connection on the API side on first creation so that you do not need to establish a new one on each request? Happy to attempt a more detailed answer if you update the question with details on the problem + expected behavior!

Comment: @rexessilfie Nope. The problem is that the connection always stays open on the Next.js API. And it's not easy to close it by detecting client disconnect. Additionally, I'd need a connection on the API side per connection on the client side. Otherwise, connections for all users would be closed. Probably, the simple solution would be to make the authenticated SSE request from the client side only. Not something I like. Because the access token would be exposed on the client side.

Comment: Have you considered this approach? On first request with your next api SSE endpoint, add a cookie that uniquely identifies the client, and save the response object in a map with key as this unique identifier. When your next api receives the SSE from the backend source, propagate to all clients in the map. On the client side, you can setup a poll on a separate (or the same endpoint) to tell your next api to keep the connection open. If your api does not receive a ping for a client in X amount of time, then you can end the connection. How does this sound?

Comment: Hey @BranislavLazic, if you're using the first answer with `no-cache. no-transform` plus this part in your `/api/events/index.js`: 
`
 req.on("close", async () => {
      reader.cancel();
      res.end();
    });`

Comment: @rexess A year later response... :) While your proposition doesn't sound bad, it kind of denies the whole purpose of SSE. If I have to poll the Next server to check for open connections, then the poll could be a solution to the whole problem. Basically, poll the Next server from the client and propagate the request with the access token to the API. Yeah, SSE would be more real-time, but still...

Answer (score 3):

The problem happens because default nextJs server compress everything by default.

Just add `'Content-Encoding': 'none'` in your `writeHead` stage and everything should work as you wished.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Working for me: `res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'none')`